# Having problem with readline() method in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file named as *test.txt* which only contains text : *This is line 1*

```
file = open("test.txt")
print(file.readline())
```

now when I run this code, I get output:

```
ÿþThis is line 1
```

Why am I getting this *ÿþ* at the beginning of the output??

Comment: looks like your extra file contains some extra bytes in the front

Answer (score 1):

Your file is UTF-16 encoded with a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) prefix (to indicate the byte order), but your locale's default encoding is a Western European-like locale (e.g. `latin-1` or `cp1252`), which interprets the BOM bytes (0xff followed by 0xfe) as `ÿþ`. The extraneous `NUL` bytes between each ASCII character that UTF-16 includes are likely being ignored.

Explicitly providing the correct encoding to `open` will let it seamlessly decode correctly, e.g.

```
with open("test.txt", encoding='utf-16') as file:
    print(file.readline())
```

Note that I switched to using a `with` statement for deterministic cleanup; the only changed needed to fix the code is adding `encoding='utf-16'` to the `open` arguments.

Answer (score -1):

try using this

```
file1 = open("test.txt","r", encoding = "utf-16")
```

Comment: or just with open("test.txt", 'r')

Comment: This is the correct answer, but it would be good to explain it a bit more. The "random characters" the OP is seeing are the [byte-order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) for UTF-16. Hence, opening in the default of UTF-8 is not correct, they need UTF-16 encoding.

Comment: @TomPlanche: Without the `encoding`, it defaults to the wrong one for the OP, so `open("test.txt", 'r')` is useless. You don't need to provide the `mode` explicitly; `'r'` is already the default. Also, minor nitpick: PEP8 style guidelines don't put spaces around the `=` for arguments passed by keyword.

Comment: @TomPlanche Not at all! Teaching well is difficult, and we get better by practice :) Welcome to SO!